# struct assignment: segment fault 11

Tags: c, struct, clang

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union value {
    long long i;
    unsigned long long u;
    double d;
    long double ld;
    void *p;
    void (*g) ();
};

struct foo {
    struct {
        union value max;
        union value min;
    }limits;
};

struct bucket_info {
    void *p;                    // free position
    void *limit;                // end position
    struct bucket_info *next;   // next bucket
};

#define NODES 8192

void * my_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if (!p)
        exit(1);
    memset(p, 0, size);
    return p;
}

void * alloc_bucket(size_t size)
{
    struct bucket_info *pb;

    pb = my_malloc(sizeof(struct bucket_info) + size);
    pb->p = pb + 1;
    pb->limit = (char *)pb->p + size;
    return pb;
}

void * alloc_for_size(struct bucket_info *s, size_t size)
{
    void *ret;

    while (s->next)
        s = s->next;

    if ((char *)s->p + size > (char *)s->limit) {
        struct bucket_info *pb = alloc_bucket(size * NODES);
        s->next = pb;
        s = pb;
    }

    ret = s->p;
    s->p = (char *)s->p + size;
    return ret;
}

static void * alloc_node(struct bucket_info **s, size_t size)
{
    if (!*s)
        *s = alloc_bucket(size * NODES);
    return alloc_for_size(*s, size);
}

static struct bucket_info *foo_info;
void * alloc_foo_node()
{
    void *ret = alloc_node(&foo_info, sizeof(struct foo));
    return ret;
}

struct foo * new_foo()
{
    return alloc_foo_node();
}

void test(int t, struct foo *foo1)
{
    struct foo *foo2 = new_foo();
    // Crash at this line
    *foo2 = *foo1;
    // comment this switch statement, it works. why?
    switch (t) {
        case 1:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct foo *foo1 = new_foo();
    test(10, foo1);

    return 0;
}
```

Above is the complete code. And I've compiled it with clang, got a 'Segment Fault 11' at line:

```
*foo2 = *foo1;
```

Then, change this line to:

```
memcpy(foo2, foo1, sizeof(struct Foo));
```

It works.

Then I've tried compiled these two cases with gcc, there is no problem.

Comment: There is no error in the code you have posted. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE) as described in the posting guidelines.

Comment: A possible problem is that `alloc_bucket` does not set `pb->next = NULL` but your code appears to reply on that

Comment: The allocated memory via my_malloc is memset to zero.

Comment: that sets all-bytes-zero, but null pointers are not necessarily that

Comment: but I've debugged, the 'next' pointer is NULL, and it also crashed.

Comment: yes, the code is copied directly from my editor. I have not tried valgrind. Can you figure out what might cause it crash?

Comment: yes, see the answer I posted

Comment: there are a few/several problems.  1) always check the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful.  2) always check the returned value from the sub functions to assure the operation was successful. 3) one reason for the crash to the method of allocation of ** .  suggest a significant re-design.  in general, allocate the array of pointers then in a loop allocate the memory that each pointer points to. make additions by using realloc on either the individual allocations or on the initial array of pointers.  Always clear 'new' areas to NULL or '\0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by `alloc_foo_node` may not be correctly aligned for `struct foo`.

On my system, printing `_Alignof(struct foo)` gives `16`, but the pointers `foo1` and `foo2` are not multiples of `16`.

So it causes undefined behaviour to convert the unaligned result of `alloc_foo_node` to have type `struct foo *`.

To fix this you have to muck around a lot more with your allocation code, to make sure that it only ever hands out space that is on the correct boundary for `struct foo`.  You could use `max_align_t` to help with this (it is defined so that `_Alignof(max_align_t)` is the biggest possible alignment required).

Comment: Disassembly shows that clang uses `movaps` here, while gcc uses `movq` (amd64). So that is indeed the case. With correct alignment it works fine.

Comment: @keltar thanks for that. I didn't get any runtime error using mingw/x86_64 so I figured OP was on some other system, didn't know clang did that :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I've tried under clang, include stddef.h and stdalign.h, compiled with options -std=c11, it complained "use of undeclared identifier 'max_align_t'"

Comment: @noinput as far as I'm aware it was added only in clang 3.4

Comment: @noinput try aligning to some nice value, like 16 bytes

Comment: `stdint.h` is the required header (if the compiler supports c11 in this regard of course). But as keltar says, 16 is a likely value for its alignment